# Сериализация в Android

Tags: java, android, serialize

Помогите, пожалуйста, с проблемой. Есть `ArrayList` `ArrayList'ов`, каждый из которых содержит экземпляр объекта. Как можно его сериализовать и в дальнейшем десериализовать? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишут, что без разницы что у тебя находится в `ArrayList`-e, главное чтобы объекты были сериализованными, т.е. ваш класс должен бын имплементирован от интерфеса `Serializable`

Сериализация:

```
try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(sdDir + serFile);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(arrayList);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Десереализация:

```
try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sdDir + serFile);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
            arrayList = (ArrayList<ItemList>) in.readObject(); 
            Log.i("palval", "dir.exists()");
            in.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Получается, чтобы сериалазовать и десериализовать, нужно вместо "arrayList" поставить свой массив? А что прописывать вместо (ArrayList<ItemList>)? ArayList<ArrayList<Object>>?

Comment: Угу, должно сработать